# How to use Shaders with BackDropFilter in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, image, dart, shader

I want this type of effect in Flutter and it seems the Pixelation shader will work.
Simple BackdropFilter with blur do the Trick but i want Pixel Blur (Boxy Blur).
but using Shaders with `BackdropFilter` Nothing Happens. (Or It Blur the Foreground part that i dont want.
Do you have any guide to use it with `BackdropFilter`?

Here's My code:

Package: [Flutter_shaders](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_shaders)

Flutter doctor: Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on macOS 12.6.6 21G646 darwin-x64, locale
en-US)

I tried this:

```
 showDialog(
            barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
            barrierDismissible: true,
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return ShaderBuilder(
                (context, shader, child1) {
                  return AnimatedSampler(
                    (image, size, canvas) {
                      shader.setFloatUniforms((uniforms) {
                        uniforms
                          ..setFloat(150)
                          ..setFloat(150)
                          ..setSize(size);
                      });

                      shader.setImageSampler(0, image);
                      canvas.drawRect(
                        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
                        Paint()..shader = shader,
                      );
                    },
                    child: BackdropFilter(
                      filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                        sigmaX: 6,
                        sigmaY: 6,
                      ),
                      child: AlertDialog(
                        insetPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        elevation: 0,
                        shape: const CircleBorder(),
                        content: SizedBox(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.29,
                            child: child),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                assetKey: 'packages/flutter_shaders/shaders/pixelation.frag',
              );
            });
```

but i want this:
Reference Image:
Instagram Profile View

Expected Behavior:
[image: Instagram Profile Image View]